# Perl Excel - Inserting an empty row with row,col numbers from vairable

Tags: perl, excel, ole, win32ole

When trying to insert an empty row using the following code

> my $StartRow = "101"; my $StartCol = "1";
>
> $Sheet->Cells($StartRow,$StartCol)->EntireRow->Insert;

**Error Occurred: Win32::OLE(0.1709) error 0x800a03ec
    in METHOD/PROPERTYGET "Cells" at 1_SPNV3G_WSS-MGW_1_0_Chicago.pl line 1732.**

**Win32::OLE(0.1709) error 0x80010108: "The object invoked has disconnected
from its clients"
    in METHOD/PROPERTYGET "Close" at 1_SPNV3G_WSS-MGW_1_0_Chicago.pl line 6310.**

Where as if I give the the values directly, no issue observed.

> $Sheet->Cells(101,1)->EntireRow->Insert;

Any thoughts?

P.S. I am referring this thread for Insert row. http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=882700

Comment: How about changing the double quotes to single quotes.

Comment: nope...single quote didnt help either :(

Answer (score 1):

Because, Perl infers the types of variables dynamically. Variables `$StartRow` and `$StartCol` are considered as strings as you enclosed their assigned values in quotes. Remove the quotes and they'll work, as the 'Cells' method expects integers as arguments. or try

```
$StartRow = int ($StartRow);
$StartCol = int ($StartCol);
```

This should work. I encountered this recently while doing this

```
my ($i, $j) = split (/\s*,\s*/, $address);
print "\n".$sheet->Cells($i, $j)->{Value};
```

Here the values returned from the split operation were considered as strings. Then I converted them to integers and it worked.